# Domino designer/notes xpages @DbColumn

Tags: xpages, designer, lotus-domino

I would like to ask for a help with some beginner issue. I have server named 'xx/yy' and i would like to view in combobox list of users from names.nsf . I created custom controller in designer and added combobox to it. I added this custom control to xpage.

I tried to use formula :

```
@DbColumn(@DbName()+"names.nsf","People",1);
```

Can anybody give me some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `@DbName()+"names.nsf"` wil end up concatenating your current database name and `names.nsf` so it won't work. <strike>Also I don't think there is a `People` view in `names.nsf`</strike>. Try this:

```
@DbColumn("names.nsf", "($VIMPeople)", 1)
```

Comment: FYI: There is a "People" view.  It's even the default view when you open names.nsf.

Comment: Also, @DbName() returns a collection ([server, filepath]), not a string, so concatenating a string is risky at best.

Comment: VIM = Vendor Independent Mail.  That was Lotus' proposal for a standard mail API which would work for different systems.  It was their competitor to Microsoft's proposal for MAPI.  Lotus implemented VIM for Notes and cc:Mail, but it never even took off.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz: Thanks for the explanation. I never knew it :)

Comment: sorry that i am that late , but i cant still get any result to combo box. even with ur code. I used ur code but still no response. Dont i need to point somewhere my domino server where names.nsf is located?

Comment: @MartinFric: Try this: `var dbname = new Array("MyServer/Acme", "names.nsf");@DbColumn(dbname, "($VIMPeople)", 1)`